# how to fix search bar to get SQL data using node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, postgresql

I am using node.js with PostgreSQL

can't find what mistake to search the data...

Is it this js part miss some code?

**Here is js**

```
app.get('/search',async function(req,res){
    const {keyword} = req.query

    const result = (await client.query(`select users.full_name from users where role = '${keyword}'`)).rows
    console.log(result)
    res.json(result)
})
```

```
document.querySelector('#search-form')
    .addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const form = event.target;
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('keyword', form.keyword.value);

        const res = await fetch('/search', {
            method: "GET",
        })
        const result = await res.json()
        console.log(result)

        loadSearchData()
    })
```

Comment: you are bot passing the formData

Comment: You need to pass `formData` as body in your fetch call. See (https://javascript.info/formdata)

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS HTML CODE

```
<form action="/search" method="GET" class="form-inline" id="search-form">
  <input name="keyword" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">

  <div class="searchBox">
  </div>
</form>
```